# Ionic and crosswalk plugin

Tags: cordova, gradle, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin, crosswalk-runtime

I'm using Crosswalk for my ionic project. The problem I'm facing is on Android when I run a debug build, the ssl works fine, however on release build it doesn't work. I have found out the solution which is to make a code change on the 'onReceivedSslError function' in a java file. So i went ahead and did the code change and built the project, but the issue is still there. the java file i made a change on is under the plugins folder (not in the platforms > android folder). I suspected that java file doesn't update when i do 'cordova build android', so i made test and deleted all the code in that file before building it, and nothing has broke when I ran the project. I'm seeing an 'xwalk.gradle' file in the plugins, which i have no idea what it does, but i'm suspecting it has something to do with making changes on the crosswalk java files. Please help

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask this will help you to rephrase your question so that you will get the potential answer.